# printing objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print these `car_object[objectname]` objects, but not sure how to do it....
I also have a Cars class.  When I do `print(car_object[objectname])` I get `ObjectmeA160
<__main__.Cars object at 0x027FB970>`.  what am I doing wrong?

```
def __iter__(self):
    car_object = {}
    cursor = self._db.execute('SELECT IDENT, MAKE, MODEL, DISPLACEMENT, 
      POWER, LUXURY FROM CARS')
    for row in cursor:
        car_object = {}
        objectname = 'Object'+str(row['IDENT'])
        car_object[objectname] = Cars(ident = row['IDENT'], make = row['MAKE'], 
                  model = row['MODEL'], disp = row['DISPLACEMENT'], power = row['POWER'], luxury = row['LUXURY'])
        print(car_object[objectname])
        yield dict(row)

class Cars:  
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.variables = kwargs

    def set_Variable(self, k, v):
        self.variables[k] = v

    def get_Variable(self, k):
        return self.variables.get(k, None)
```

Comment: That depends *entirely* on the `Cars` class. Does it have a `.__str__()` menthod?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters added Cars class...how does a __str__() would work in this case?

Comment: Are you printing anything else before that `print()` statement? The `<__main__.Cars object at 0x027FB970>` is for your `Cars` class, the part in front is not.

Comment: And what *would* you like to print instead?

Comment: I am printing the objectname I create 'objectname = 'Object'+str(row['IDENT'])'

Comment: I would like to print the IDENT, MAKE, MODEL, DISPLACEMENT, POWER.

Comment: and LUXURY, all of what is created in here ' car_object[objectname] = Cars(ident = row['IDENT'], make = row['MAKE'], 
                  model = row['MODEL'], disp = row['DISPLACEMENT'], power = row['POWER'], luxury = row['LUXURY'])'

Comment: I gave you a starting point in my answer below. Adjust the method return value as needed to tweak your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<__main__.Cars object at 0x027FB970>` is the standard string for custom objects that do not implement their own [`.__str__()` hook](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). You can customize it by implementing that method:

```
class Cars:
    # ....

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Car instance with variables: {!r}'.format(self.variables)
```

Comment: how do I call this iteratively to print them all?  I am getting the input from the db...which has about 30some rows so i want to print them all. do i call from main?

Comment: @user2096860: You are doing it correctly to print them all. This hook gives your objects a way to be printed in a different way, so instead of `<__main__.Cars object at 0x027FB970>` it'll print whatever this method returns.